# FileNotFound when sending mail with attachment with Javamail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a mail with an attachment file by using Javamail. But when the code is trying to read the content of the file a FileNoFound exception is raised.
The weird thing is that in debug mode I can see that it gets the file (the MultiPartFile variable isn't empy). I'm also using @Async so maybe it's the real issue.

My method sendMail :

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void sendMail(Context ctx, String dest, String subject, String templateName, MultipartFile attachment)
            throws MessagingException, MailException, IOException {

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        message.setFrom("test@test.com");
        message.setTo(dest);
        message.setSubject(subject);

        String htmlContent = emailTemplateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true); // true = isHtml

        if (attachment != null) {
            InputStreamSource attachmentSource;
            attachmentSource = new ByteArrayResource(attachment.getBytes());
            message.addAttachment(attachment.getOriginalFilename(), attachmentSource);
        }

        emailSender.send(mimeMessage);      

    }
```

The error I'm having is :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.970471969296194243.8080\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_a28782c3_18d7_4b6b_84b7_2d9e81e9a692_00000007.tmp 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.getBytes(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:245)
[...]
```

Edit: I tried removing the @Async and the file is uploaded without any errors. So this is the cause of my FileNotFound exception... So is there any way to solve this because I would very much like to put this method on async. I don't know much about async and thread managing so maybe I just can't use it when uploading files (?)

Comment: Async means that you should not trigger sendMail on Upload, but on Upload completed. I hope others can correct me, but it is quite a bit of redesign. Some message queue perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not seem to explain what is `emailTemplateEngine` is.
usually your server does not copy custom templates by default. check dir `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.970471969296194243.8080\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\`
it should be defined out of the box.
you can try using `freemarker.template.Configuration`

```java
private Configuration initialiseFreeMarkerConfiguration() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
    factory.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/ROOT/");
    factory.setPreferFileSystemAccess(false);
    return factory.createConfiguration();
  }
```

your code...

```java
  private final Configuration freeMarkerConfiguration;
// in method
 MimeMessage mimeMessage = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        message.setFrom("test@test.com");
        message.setTo(dest);
        message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(processEmailFromTemplate(model), true);

//attachment logic, use FileSystemResource  instead of ByteArrayResource
if (attachment != null) {
            InputStreamSource attachmentSource;
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(attachment));
            message.addAttachment(attachment.getOriginalFilename(), file );
        }

 emailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

method `processEmailFromTemplate()` should do something like this.

```java
private String processEmailFromTemplate(Map<String, Object> model) throws IOException, TemplateException {
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(freeMarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("your template name"), model));
return content.toString();
}
```

Comment: emailTemplateEngine is autowired from org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine. I don't have any issue with the template processing because it works fine when I don't have any attachment. Also I just tried removing the @Async annotation on the method and it upload the file without any issue. I'll update my post with that information

Comment: you will need to use FileSystemResource  in you're attaching files.

Comment: I've tried to uplad the file like that but I keep having the same mistake. Maybe I just can't upload a file on async

Comment: do you have `@EnableAsync` on top of the class ?

Comment: No I have it ony my Configuration class. I've just tried adding it to the class with the sendMail method but it's the same result

Comment: from which class are you calling `sendMail` . FYI, `@Async` has limitation that you can't call it from the same class method defined. source : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: I'm sending it from a service class (@Service)